# Hive alter table add columns issue when running using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, alter-table

I have input dataframe as below: df_input

```
|a |b |c |mon|src_id|
|5 |2 |3 |1  |A     |
|1 |5 |4 |2  |A     |
|1 |5 |3 |2  |B     |
```

**Partitioned on mon and src_id.**

Now, I want to add a new column to the existing partition. Tried with below command after loading into table:

```
df_input.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy().format("parquet").saveAsTable(db_name.table_name)
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE data_base.table_name ADD COLUMNS (d long) CASCADE")
```

But getting the below error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException" "\nextraneous input 'CASCADE' exception <EOF>(line 1, pos 63)\n\n== SQL ==\nALTER TABLE data_base.table_name ADD COLUMNS (d long) CASCADE\n .......
```

Tried and not succeeded to find where is the issue in the alter table command.

Comment: Still getting error, not sure where is the problem when running from sqark.sql()

Comment: from spark connected to beeline using url and used process command imported in python and executed the command by opening a shell. It worked and altered the table for the old partitions precent in the partitioned table.

Answer (score 0):

from spark connected to beeline using url and used process command imported in python and executed the command by opening a shell. It worked and altered the table for the old partitions precent in the partitioned table.